# Writing a constraint with cplex python

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, cplex

I shared the parameters, variables and notation of the model:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have difficulty in writing equation 7, which is one of the constraints of the model, with cplex. The code block I wrote is as follows:

```
mdl.add_constraints(T[i, j, k] >=  mdl.sum(p[l]*y[i, l, s] + s[l]*x[i, l, s] for l in N for s in ???)- d[j] - 100000*(1 - x[i, j, k])   
                for i in M
                for j in N
                for k in N) #7
```

Could you please help me about this? It will be very welcome. If desired, I can also share all the model code I wrote.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The "kicker" (hard part) in that constraint is the fact that the range of the sum over `s` is bounded by the index `k`.  Because your indices are numerical, you could just use a `range` command to generate the appropriate subset.

**caution:**  you have 2 elements named `s` in there, so you will need to rename one.  I changed your index variable.

also:

- you had `mdl.sum()`  You don't / shouldn't need `mdl.` there ?
- None of your variables / sets are "model objects" unless you renamed them previously (not recommended).  I would expect to see something like `mdl.x[...]` etc. and `mdl.M` etc....

##### Code:

```
mdl.add_constraints(T[i, j, k] >=  sum(p[l]*y[i, l, s_idx] + s[l]*x[i, l, s_idx] for l in N for s_idx in range(1, k+1))- d[j] - 100000*(1 - x[i, j, k])   
                for i in M
                for j in N
                for k in N) #7
```